# increment operator in c array handling

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
  int a[10]={};
  int n=2,i;
  //a[4]=0;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%d",a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  a[++n] = n++;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

As per my understanding this should assign a value of 2 to a[4] but the gcc compiled exe prints 3 to the a[4]. What is wrong with my understanding? Please elaborate.

thanks,
muru

Comment: @luker it sets all the values in array to 0

Comment: important is you  need to learn sequence point.

Comment: You need `int a[10]={0};` for it to be standard C I think, @muru.

Comment: thanks all for the redirection